# Module not found on images

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and try to create a slider.
I want to create a slide which displays text and image on the same slide. Text display good but I can't success do display my image. I almost try everything I see in this forum but don't work.

data slider file

```
import React from 'react';
import one from "./img/first.png"

const dataSlider = [
    {
        id: 1,
        img: {one},
        title: "Summer sale",
        description: "Don't compromise on style! get flat 30% off for new arrivals",
        bg: "black",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        img:{one},
        title: "Winter sale",
        description: "Don't compromise on style! get flat 30% off for new arrivals",
        bg: "red",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        img:{one},
        title: "Popular sale",
        description: "Don't compromise on style! get flat 30% off for new arrivals",
        bg: "blue",
    },

];
export {dataSlider};
```

Slider.jsx

```
 <Arrow direction="left"  onClick={() => handleClick("left")}><ArrowLeftOutlined /></Arrow>
                <Wrapper>
                    {dataSlider.map(item =>(

                    <Slide bg={item.bg}>
                    <ImgContainer><Img  src={require( `${ item.img }` )} /></ImgContainer>
                    <InfoContainer><Title>{item.title}</Title><Description>{item.description}</Description><Button>shop now</Button></InfoContainer>
                    </Slide>

                    ))}
```

[image]

Error is: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using CRA. It would probably be easier to just add your images to the `public` folder.

Then in your `dataSlider.js` instead of importing the image, just do something like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  img: "/img/first.png", // this will point to `/public/img/first.png` in the implementation
  title: "Summer sale",
  description: "Don't compromise on style! get flat 30% off for new arrivals",
  bg: "black",
},
```

And then in it's usage you would do this:

```
<img src={item.img} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `import one from "/img/first.jpg"` points to the root of directory structure. Just remove the initial `/`.

Comment: Still not work. Module not found: Can't resolve 'img/first.jpg' in 'C:\react\Project\ecommerce\src'